# Are there ways of detecting a price bubble of an asset with no inherent value such as Bitcoin, purely based on an existing momentum in pricing?

Tags: price, bitcoin

I have heard of existing methods of detecting bubbles in the pricing of precious metals like gold and was wondering if, by extension, something similar could be done to examine prices of cryptocurrencies, and particularly Bitcoin.

Comment: I think "bubble" is something that anyone defines different. Prices are the result of supply and demand.